# How to exclude unused methods from final binary?

Tags: c++, gcc

I thought that `private` methods, which are not used inside its class are removed by the compiler/linker and would not be part of the final binary.

I have created an example class, with a private method which is implemented but not used.

```
class XXX
{
  public:
  XXX();

  private:
  void MyUnusedMethod();
};
```

And in the implementation file:

```
void XXX::MyUnusedMethod()
{
  const char* hugo = "ABCCHARLYABC";
  printf( hugo );
}
```

After compilation the string still exist in the final binary. Why? And how can I prevent this?

Best regards,
Charly

Comment: Why can't you put that method in `#if 0 ... #endif` block ?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking optimization flags for gcc ?

Comment: If you mean the `-O3` flag - it makes no difference. Of course - if I know that I won't use it any more, I'm not too lazy to remove it. But it is also a general question: Why is it not dropped by the compiler/linker?

Comment: Switch to Delphi :-P . Its smart-linker does exactly that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One portable way is to have a .o file for each function. Then build an archive .a from those .o files. When linking against that archive the linker links in only those .o files that resolve symbols, i.e. the .o files with a function that nobody calls are not linked in.

Another way is to use latest versions of gcc with [link-time code generation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-flto-835).

Comment: +1 for the link-time code generation, which seems to be the ideal solution to me!

Answer (score 7):

This is usually done by passing **-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections** options to gcc. Look this [link](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

> After compilation the string still exist in the final binary. Why

Others have given suggestions how to get rid of that unused code in your final binary. I'd like to give some answer on the `Why` a bit - here are two points why it might be impossible for the function to be removed.

Unless you declared all objects of that `XXX` type with [static linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library), the compiler cannot strip the the type (and hence the method) from the generated object file because some other object file might access the value using `extern`. The linker, which can see all object files at once, might be able to solve this.

However, since you tagged your question as `gcc`, it may be that you're not compiling and/or linking with [-fvisibility=hidden](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). In that case, even the linker cannot strip the symbol (and hence the code) because other modules might resolve the symbol at runtime.

Comment: "(and hence the method)" does not follow from the premise. Regardsless of the number of objects, if there is no call whatsoever to `MyUnusedMethod` then it need not be in the binary.

Comment: @MSalters: If the symbol of `MyUnusedMethod` is not elided in the final module (e.g. executable of shared library), it may be that some other module resolves and accesses the symbol at runtime. It's very common for code which is not used within a module to remain in the module - think of functions exposed by a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a really bad idea, but I have to write it anyway :) You could create a templated class, afair unused methods get removed.

Comment: I have to check that to be really sure, I thought I have read that somewhere. I don't have the template book at hand now :/

Comment: The answer is correct. The rationale is that `class Foo<T>` may be useful even if not all methods would compile for all values of `T`. E.g. `T==const int` might break all non-const methods of `Foo<T>`.

Comment: Templates are only instantiated if they are used, so it would work. But I would rather check the linker flags instead.